# No such module 'MobileRTC'

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I have this kind of error shown in a native iOS plugin for Flutter.

> No such module 'MobileRTC'.

Error image.

[image]

How do I solve this error?

Comment: It seems that Zoom stopped supporting their MobileRTC SDK. Latest 1.6.2 SDK download has no recollection of MobileRTC, the project is not compiling. Downloading their Swift sample from https://github.com/zoom/client-sdk-iOS-getting-started results in this error "MobileRTC module not found" because there is no such module in the repo. has nothing to do with running on real device. It seems that Zoom is no longer supports ios for their meeting SDK and only has Video SDK ( some support at least )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occur when you are trying to use `MobileRTC` and run your app by emulator. when using MobileRTC you should use a real device because emulators does not support MobileRTC